# Finding index of middle visible cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

This is the code that I currently have inside my custom CollectionView layout

```
/* Returns the item index of the currently middle cell */
var middleItemIndex: Int {
    get {
        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: collectionView!.center.x + collectionView!.contentOffset.x, 
                                  y: collectionView!.center.y + collectionView!.contentOffset.y)

        let centerCellIndexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItemAtPoint(centerPoint)

        return (centerCellIndexPath?.item)!
    }
}

override func prepareLayout() {
    print(middleItemIndex)
}
```

I keep getting `exc_bad_access` error on the line with `indexPathForItemAtPoint`. On further inspection, my stack trace shows that it keeps repeating collectionview's `prepareForLayout()` and the `featuredItemIndex` method above which leads me to believe that the code inside featuredItemIndex contains infinite loop which eventually creates stack overflow.

I fail to see what causes the error. Does calling collectionview's property inside custom layout class creates an infinite loop? If that's the case is there a way to find the index for the middle cell inside the collectionview? My collection view looks exactly like a tableview, I'm using collectionview because there will be a lot of custom interaction with the cell's layout

Answer (score 0):

I think using `indexPathsForVisibleItems` to find the middle index is better. I am not really sure the mechanism of the `indexPathForItemAtPoint`. Maybe it will relayout the cell to test if your point is in your cell or not. But actually you can use `indexPathsForVisibleItems` to get your mid indexPath easier and safer.